# How to clean up my json response to be cleaner

Tags: api, npm, node-request, eloqua

I have an index.js file that is returning the body of an Eloqua REST obj using this code:

I have tried to use `JSON.stringify` and this `prettyJOSNStringify`

```js
var request = require('request'); 
var prettyJSONStringify = require('pretty-json-stringify');

 request(  
     {  
        url : "https://secure.p03.eloqua.com/api/rest/2.0/assets/form/XXX",  
        headers : { "Authorization" : authenticationHeader }  
    },  
    function (error, response, body) {  
        console.log(prettyJSONStringify(body));  
    }  
);
```

but the response in the console is just a huge blob of JSON, how do I clean this up?

{\"type\":\"Form\",\"currentStatus\":\"Draft\",\"id\":\"912\",\"createdAt\":\"1544810248\",\"createdBy\":\"35\",\"depth\":\"complete\",\"folderId\":\"5487\",\"name\":\"Let's Connect Web Form 3.0 - Vertical\",\"permissions\":[\"Retrieve\",\"Delete\",\"Update\"],\"updatedAt\":\"1545074293\",\"updatedBy\":\"35\",\"customCSS\":\" \/* RESET *\/.elq-form * {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}.elq-form input,textarea {\u0009-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;\u0009-moz-box-sizing:content-box;\u0009box-sizing:content-box;}.elq-form input[type=text],.elq-form textarea,.elq-form select[multiple=multiple] {\u0009border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;} .elq-form button,input[type=reset],input[type=button],input[type=submit],input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio],select {\u0009-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;\u0009-moz-box-sizing:border-box;\u0009box-sizing:border-box;}\/* GENERIC *\/.elq-form input {\

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"cleaner"_... Do you mean omit the escaping, (i.e. ``\``) before the double quotes, and pretty print/indent the output. Or something else?

Comment: So yes kinda, I wanted it to do more of nested type look in my console, so that would be escaping the slashes but then but then nesting the elements in groups where appropriate.

Comment: @RobC did you have any other ideas on how to escape the "\" and do like a nesting of elements in the console.log output

Comment: Have you tried adding the properties `json: true` to your `request` options object, i.e. in the first object you pass, the one which currently specifies `url` and `headers` ? Then do `console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2))`, instead of your current `console.log(prettyJSONStringify(body));`